# how to handle click event inside html from js and external js function

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, external-js

i have external file for templates i want to adding the templates in it but when i adding the onclick functoin its show error massage the handleClickCard not defind

```
import { handleClickCard } from "../../../script.mjs";

function templateCard(item, condition, idUpdate, id, title, tags) {
  const card = `
<div class="card" >
    <div class="card-header">                 
        <span onclick="showuserinfo('${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(item),
    )}')" style="cursor: pointer;"><strong>${item.author.username
    }</strong>
        </span>
        ${condition
      ? `<button class="btn btn-danger mx-2" style="float: right;" onclick={handleclickdeletebutton('${idUpdate}')}>delete</button>`
      : ""
    }
        ${condition ? `<button class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;" onclick="handleclickeditbutton('${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(item),)}')">edit</button>`
      : ""}
    </div>

     <!-- the problem in here and there is another problem in the file but its the same solution for this problem -->
    <div class="card-body" onclick="handleClickCard(${id})">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  `;
  return card;
}
export { templateCard };
```

and handleClickCard in another file i export it

```
export const handleClickCard = () => {
    console.log("handle click")
}
```

and  the error massage that show :

Uncaught ReferenceError: handleClickCard is not defined

so how to perform the function from the external templates file ????

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I think we ran into this a while back. I believe that since the function is currently called from the inline onclick, it's out of the scope of the module. I think you'll want to use `addEventListener()` instead.

Comment: i tried but its show another error massage about can't  read null document.querySelector() ...

Comment: Okay, please include *that* code too.

Answer (score -1):

If you bouble checked if import statement are correct ?

Comment: its correct i checked alot

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Also please spell check your comments/answers

Comment: its nit an answer, please comment if you have questions

Comment: its nit an answer, please comment if you have questions

Comment: it's not working the export is correct